# How can I pass a variable control name to findViewById in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, findviewbyid

I am trying to learn Kotlin and I'm building a simple example as I go. I have 3 image buttons that open the camera and take a photo. The thumbnail is then set into an ImageView. I've used the examples from https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics?hl=en to get the basics working (figuring if I can make it work for one, it'll work for all. It does indeed work for one, but I can't figure out how to make it one function that drops the thumbnail into the correct ImageView.

Inside my onCreate I have the listener for each of the buttons that will invoke the camera:

```
camRead1.setOnClickListener {dispatchTakePictureIntent() }
camRead2.setOnClickListener {dispatchTakePictureIntent() }
camRead3.setOnClickListener {dispatchTakePictureIntent() }
```

And I took the sample from the url above:

```
val REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1

private fun dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    val takePictureIntent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
    try {
        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
    } catch (e: ActivityNotFoundException) {
        // display error state to the user
    }
}

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

    val thumb: ImageView = findViewById(R.id.thumbRead1)

    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        val imageBitmap = data.extras.get("data") as Bitmap
        thumb.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap)
    }
}
```

and pasted it into my class MainActivity, and after I replaced imageView in the override function with a variable (thumb) and added the super, it worked perfectly for the first one.

However, I am trying to get 3 photos, read1, read2, and read3 which each need to display the thumb in thumbRead1, thumbRead2 and thumbRead3. I can't figure out how the onActivityResult is executed since the call inside dispatchTakePictureIntent is calling startActivityForResult (especially as Android Studio says that startActivityForResult is deprecated).

Obviously, once onActivityResult executes, I can see that thumb defines R.id.thumbRead1 and receives imageBitmap but I don't understand how I can make it aware of the button that was clicked.

Without understanding how onActivityResult is called, I'm thinking that if I can do something like:

```
findViewById(R.id("thumbRead" + imgID))
```

to define the specific ImageView that I want the photo pasted into. Am I on the right track here? If not, what is the recommended way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note they've recently added what's supposed to be a cleaner way of starting other activities for results and getting the results, [explained here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result). But since you're already doing it the traditional way, I'll explain how to get that working.

I think the easiest thing to do in this situation is just make more request codes, so you can check which request it was.

```
val REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE_SOURCE_1 = 1
val REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE_SOURCE_2 = 2
val REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE_SOURCE_3 = 3

//...

camRead1.setOnClickListener { dispatchTakePictureIntent(REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE_SOURCE_1) }
camRead2.setOnClickListener { dispatchTakePictureIntent(REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE_SOURCE_2) }
camRead3.setOnClickListener { dispatchTakePictureIntent(REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE_SOURCE_3) }

//...

private fun dispatchTakePictureIntent(requestCode: Int) {
    val takePictureIntent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
    try {
        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, requestCode)
    } catch (e: ActivityNotFoundException) {
        // display error state to the user
    }
}

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
        // possibly show message to user
        return 
    }
    val imageViewId = when (requestCode) {
        REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE_SOURCE_1 -> R.id.thumbRead1
        REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE_SOURCE_2 -> R.id.thumbRead2
        REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE_SOURCE_3 -> R.id.thumbRead3
    }
    val imageView = findViewById<ImageView>(imageViewId)
    imageView.imageBitmap = data.extras.get("data") as Bitmap
}
```

By the way, if you want to get an ID for a view using the String like you were showing you were trying, you would do it like this:

```
val viewId = resources.getIdentifier("thumbRead$imgId", "id", packageName)
val imageView = findViewById<ImageView>(viewId)
```

Comment: Yes, Tenfour04, that was what I was getting at. In this approach it wouldn't matter how many items there were, the code would be tight in two lines. Thanks for the link to the new approach too. I won't pretend to understand it just yet, but I'll be looking to implement that approach for v2.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass different request code for each call and pass it to the **dispatchTakePictureIntent** function. You do not need to get id by findviewbyid. You simply can add the image on the basis of the request code.

```
val REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE_ONE = 1
val REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE_TWO = 2
val REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE_THREE = 3

private fun dispatchTakePictureIntent(requestCode: Int) {
     val takePictureIntent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
     try {
        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, requestCode)
     } catch (e: ActivityNotFoundException) {
    // display error state to the user
     }
}

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
   if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
       val imageBitmap = data.extras.get("data") as Bitmap
      if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE_ONE ) { 
         thumbRead1.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap)
      }else if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE_TWO ) { 
         thumbRead2.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap)
      }else if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE_THREE ) { 
         thumbRead3.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap)
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you. This works exactly as described. Does Kotlin not have an option to build the object name/id so that it can be called as a single line that builds the ID of the ImageView rather than a multiple if? For my purpose there are only 3 items, but what if there were 50 items?

Comment: @TimFoster see the bottom of my answer.